# Port over existing MVC user authentication to Azure functions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, jwt, azure-functions

I have an old web application which is using ASP.net with the build in cookie based authentication which has the standard ASP.net SQL tables for storing the users credentials.

[image]

This is currently running as an Azure web app, but I was toying with the idea of trying to go serverless as per this example creating a ReactJs SPA hosting on blob storage to try and keep costs down and also improve performance without breaking the bank.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/serverless/web-app

I was wondering if it is possible to port over the existing ASP.net authentication to Azure functions, to instead return a JWT (JSON Web Token) which could be passed back in the headers to handle authenticated requests.

When I have tried this in the past I have failed misserably, so I was wondering if anyone knows if it is possible?

I've seen this article, which seems to talk about Azure functions doing authentication, but with Azure AD, which I don't think is right for what I need.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2018/02/19/azure-functions-and-app-service-authentication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is kind of. What I mean by this is that you can use your existing database and many of the same libraries, but you can't port over the code configuration. The default authentication for Functions is either 1) The default API tokens or 2) one of the EasyAuth providers baked into App Services which is in the guide you linked. Currently, any other solution you'll need to setup yourself.

Assuming you go with the JWT option, you'll need to turn off all of the built-in authentication for Functions. This includes setting your HttpRequest functions to `AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous`.

At a basic level You'll need to create two things. A function to issue tokens, and either a DI service or a custom input binding to check them.

***Issuing tokens***

The Functions 2.x+ runtime is on .NET Core so I'm gong to borrow some code from [this blog post](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) that describes using JWTs with Web API. It uses `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` to generate a token, which we could then return from the Function.

```
public SecurityToken Authenticate(string username, string password)
{
   //replace with your user validation
    var user = _users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == username && x.Password == password);

    // return null if user not found
    if (user == null)
        return null;

    // authentication successful so generate jwt token
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] 
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
    return tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
}
```

***Validating Tokens***
There are several guides out there for validating JWT within Azure Functions. I like this one from Ben Morris: https://www.ben-morris.com/custom-token-authentication-in-azure-functions-using-bindings/ ([source code](https://github.com/BenMorris/FunctionsCustomSercuity)). It describes authenticating with either a custom input binding or with DI. Between the two, DI is the preferred option, unless there is a specific reason you need to use a binding. Here again, its the  `Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens` and `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` libraries that you'll need to do the bulk of the work.

```
public class ExampleHttpFunction
{
    private readonly IAccessTokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public ExampleHttpFunction(IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    [FunctionName("ExampleHttpFunction")]
    public IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "example")] HttpRequest req,  ILogger log)
    {
        var result = _tokenProvider.ValidateToken(req);

        if (result.Status == AccessTokenStatus.Valid)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Request received for {result.Principal.Identity.Name}.");
            return new OkResult();
        }
        else
        {
            return new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's brilliant i'll give that a try thanks so much for your help and the time taken to write this answer